# proving that a point is the center of a circle

Tags: geometry

Given $AB,AC$ tangents to two circles at points $B,C$ in the picture.

[image]

$AB=2AE$, $DE=10+AB$.

$O_1$ is the middle point of chord $DE$.

Need to prove that the point $O_1$ is the center of the left circle.

I can't see how it can be done.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be an error in the formulation of the problem. For if that's generally true, then it is impossible to have 10 (a constant) in DE = 10 + AB.

Comment: @Mok-KongShen: Well it's still possible, just that that condition is redundant and will merely tell us the exact lengths of everything.

Comment: But then there is not enough information, and indeed $O_1$ may not be the centre of the circle.

Comment: A pity the picture isn't here...

Answer (score 1):

I also think that some information is missing here. I can show how far I could get:

If we can show that $O_1C=O_1E$ (or $O_1C=O_1D$) we are finished because a circle is fixed by three points which are not on a straight line. This is equivalent to showing that $O_1C=5+AE$ by using the two given formulas.

1. Because AC is the tangent of circle 1 through C, we can use pythagoras for the triangle ($O_1C,AC,O_1A$) and get: $O_1C^2=O_1A^2-AC^2$
2. So considering $O_1A$, we can observe that $O_1A=O_1E+AE$ by construction and since $O_1E=0.5DE=5+AE$ by definition of $O_1$ being the middle point of chord DE (first equality) and using the two given formulas (second equality), we have: $O_1A=5+AE+AE=5+2AE$
3. Now consider AC. Either by obvserving that AC also is tangent of circle 2 through C and using pythagoras for the triangles ($AC,O_2C,O_2A$) and ($O_2B,AB,O_2A$) or alternatively by just seeing we get AC=AB, so finally by first given formula: $AC=2AE$
4. Now we plug (2.) and (3.) into (1.) and get $$\begin{align}O_1C^2&=O_1A^2-AC^2=\\&=(5+2AE)^2-(2AE)^2\\&=25+20AE+4AE^2-4AE^2\\&=25+20AE\end{align}$$
5. Remember from the beginning that we have to show $O_1C=5+AE$. Assuming that the statement in the OP is true, we can plug this into (4.): $$\begin{align}25+20AE& \overset{!}{=}(5+AE)^2\\25+20AE&=25+10AE+AE^2\\20AE&=10AE+AE^2\\20&=10+AE\\10&=AE\end{align}$$

So **if** $AE=10$, the statement is proven. Otherwise these calculations may become completely obsolete.

Feel free to point out any errors.

Comment: i think something is missing as well. probably that's why i couldn't prove it. thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: No problem. You should have a look at the comments to your original post to understand why something seems to be missing. And Don Antonio seems to know something we haven't seen yet. I can only say that I tried to get some measures out of the picture in order to find a x such that $DE=10x+AB$ but that x doesn't match any of the given distances... (like $DE=10O_2B+AB$ or something...)

Comment: Okay, probably DonAntonio only meant what user127.0.0.1 did via edit (integrate the picture here on M.SE). I thought he probably wanted to say "A pity there's no picture..." (irony, you know...) like "because if there was one, everybody could see easily what went wrong with that constant '10'...". ;) So forget what I said about his comment.